# Num_rows doesn't work?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Database but my function is not working. I want to know how many results I get for my database query, but I just get nothing back, not even 0. I also tried `$values->num_rows;` same result. Do not get back a number... just nothing

My Code:

```
$values = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `wp_all_import_xml` WHERE name = '$title' AND price = '$price' AND shop = '$shop' AND link = '$link'");

$count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values);

echo "ERROR by detecting Product (More than 1 Row return by SQL!): " .$title. " Preis: " .$price. " Shop: " .$shop. " Link: " .$link. "\t num_rows: " .$count_values. "\n";
```

How can I get the amount of rows I get returned?

Greetings

Comment: Turn error reporting ON.

Comment: By "get nothing back" do you mean your `echo` statement successfully runs but the `$count_values` variable is empty?  What's in the other variables?  What *specifically* happens?  Your code is open to SQL injection so we don't even really know what SQL statement you're actually executing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get displayed a value... - But the SQL statement doesn't matter... I should get 0 back even if my SQL statement is wrong...

Comment: @Jan If the SQL query gets an error, `$values` will be `false`, which isn't a valid argument to `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Comment: How should the query get an error? - Gets the SQL query an error if nothing is returned or get does it gets back a 0?

Comment: If you didn't successfully connect to the db?

Comment: We can guess all the day without seeing the error message..

Comment: Connection is established before! - I can see that in the log. How can I check if I got an error back or not?

Comment: Okay, got it! - I get an error if nothing is returned. Right?

Comment: @Jan it's important the question provides enough information. Showing the errors you get (sure sensitive information can be excluded or masked/changed), and the context of the code. Otherwise those who want to help, would have to keep guessing. From this posted snippet, I assume `$database` is a `mysqli` object. If your SQL query is not correct, the `$database->query()` will return `FALSE` so you can assert that in your code. Otherwise it'll be a `mysqli result object` which you can get the number of rows as `$values->num_rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqli_num_rows function does work.

The most likely explanation for the observed behavior is an error is occurring and being ignored.

For debugging this, start with making sure error reporting is enabled.

Modify the code to check the return from the query. Verify that it's not returning FALSE, by performing a conditional test.

```
if ($values = $mysqli->query(...) ) {
   // query returned a resultset
} else {
   // query returned FALSE
}
```

If all we need to retrieve is the number of rows, then we can use COUNT(*) in the SELECT list.

```
if ( $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ... ") ) {
```

If the query is successful, then we get a row back, even if the count is zero. And we can easily process the result like we process results from other queries,  without the need to muck with `num_rows`, and worrying about whether the query is buffered or unbuffered, etc.

---

We're going to assume that `$database` is a mysqli connection, and not a PDO connection, since the code includes a call to the `mysqli_num_rows` function.  If it's PDO connection, then "num_rows doesn't work".

---

The code in the question follows the pattern frequently seen in code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. (In this excerpt, we can't determine if the values of the variables being included in the SQL text are potentially unsafe, so we can't tell if it's vulnerable or not.)

If this was a prepared statement with bind placeholders, then we could tell.
Use prepared statements with bind placeholders. It isn't hard.

Comment: I got the solution already. I get an error back. My question now is, do I get an error back if nothing is found or when something else is wrong?

Because I checked the value manually in phpMyAdmin and there I get exactly one value back for my SELECT query

Comment: A query that successfully executes and returns an empty resultset is not an error condition, In terms of MySQL, SQL, mysqli, it's perfectly valid to execute a query that returns zero rows. The resultset will be empty. That's valid. If you prefer to actually get a row that has the count, then use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. This is usually more efficient than returning a large resultset back to the client.

Comment: I checked now the query with `$database->error` and got my error. Used the wrong row name!